# does ubuntu-sdk all programming language supports all mobile devices?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

ive installed ubuntu-sdk , and the main goal for this installation is to develop mobile apps, for all devices iphone/galaxy...etc

saw the project programming language select, html5....python.
can i develop mobile apps similar to phoneGap ?

best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we support most of the PhoneGap (Cordova) APIs, see http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/ for more information on that.

You can also use QML/Javascript on any Ubuntu device (phone, tablet or desktop).

Comment: thank you for the reply , now am dealing with Cordova error in SDK,  `Cannot create CordovaView object.`